# Storing multiple textures in a single texture

Tags: opengl, graphics, sprite, textures

I'm trying to store several 2D sprites inside a single texture, since I figured out that it would be much faster than having to bind a different texture every time a different sprite needs to be painted.

The sizes of the big texture are powers of two. The question is about the sizes of the smaller "subtextures". Technically they can be of any size, but will making their sizes to be powers of two as well will result in better performance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but will making their sizes to be powers of two as well will result in better performance?

No. You're just drawing textured quads. And there is nothing special about using texture coordinates that just so happen to map to texels that are on powers of two.

Comment: Further question... I stumbled upon this article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_atlas which describes my approach pretty closely, except it seems to mention powers of two. Can you explain why?

Comment: Primarily because of mipmapping. Powers-of-two scale down easier and don't have bleed-over (well, until a certain point). You're using these for sprites, which I'm guessing don't have mipmaps.